# Collapse pasting a list structure includes escaped quotes and c() in R

Tags: r, list, paste

Forgive me if this is very basic but it's driving me mad.

I have a large nested list object, where the 'leaf' elements are character vectors. A simple representation of this is:

```
dummy <- list(c('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

I simply want to paste the items together with a pipe separator, like this:

```
paste0('Start > ', paste(dummy, collapse='|'), ' > End')
```

so that I get the output

```
Start > A|B|C > End
```

but what I get is

```
[1] "Start > c(\"A\", \"B\", \"C\") > End"
```

where I have all these additional characters and escaped quotes. What am I doing wrong?

I'm reticent to use unlist() even with recursive = FALSE as this collapses my three character sequences.

Comment: Just do it `dummy <- c('A', 'B', 'C')` don't use list

Comment: It's already a list. This is predefined by a wider structure so I've just tried to simulate this for a replicable example.

Comment: i mean don't use the list use this `dummy <- c('A', 'B', 'C')`
Then `paste0('Start > ', paste(dummy, collapse='|'), ' > End')`

Comment: Can you share the structure of your list ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies; Val's solution is what I'm after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example, this works:

```
dummy <- list(c('A', 'B', 'C'))

> sprintf('Start > %s > End',paste0(unlist(dummy),collapse = '|'))
[1] "Start > A|B|C > End"
```

If you have multiple entries in your list and you want to put them all in the same pipe, you can use the same approach:

```
dummy2 <- list(dummy[[1]],c('D','E','F'))

> sprintf('Start > %s > End',paste0(unlist(dummy2),collapse = '|'))
[1] "Start > A|B|C|D|E|F > End"
```

Or if you'd like to keep the entries separated, use lapply:

```
> lapply(dummy2, function(x) sprintf('Start > %s > End',paste0(x,collapse = '|')))

[[1]]
[1] "Start > A|B|C > End"

[[2]]
[1] "Start > D|E|F > End"
```

Answer (score 0):

If only one element of your `list` is a `character` vector as shown, then you can try `rapply`.

```
rapply(object = dummy,classes = "character",
            function(t){paste0("Start > ",paste(t,collapse = "|")," > End")})
```